# Why are ellipse polygones simplified when used in a FeatureService?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, oracle-spatial, feature-service, st-geometry

I have polygons with ellipse shape in a SDE Oracle ST_GEOMETRY geodatabase. All those polygons are correctly displayed when in a MapService. But when displayed in a FeatureService, some polygons undergo deformation. It's like they were simplified.

I'm using Oracle 11g and ArcGIS 10.0

[image]

Comment: Likely reason is that feature services don't support ellipse shaped features and they are simplified (the same happens with some advanced symbology): http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0154000003nt000000. Map services create a rasterized image of the vector data first and send just an image to the client, so the source shape doesn't matter for them.

Comment: This is very deceiving!!! How am I supposed to edit my features?

Comment: I am not 100% sure if this is the reason though. You are supposed to use technology that supports this workflow such as a desktop application or a web-based solution with the support for ellipse shaped features.

Comment: I'm using the ArcGIS Flex API. Doesn't it support ellipse shapes?

Comment: It's not the API limitation, it's the feature service limitation (think ArcGIS Server) (if it is, as I said I am just making an educated guess).

Comment: This is really annoying. Not all polygons are simplified. It happens randomly!

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov Symbols are downgraded as explained in the document you referenced. 

The document desn't speak about downgrading geometries. However, this is what it seems to happen.